# What's the maths symbol for alternation of product and sums?

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, products

Is there a mathematics symbol for referring to the equation below?

> [(((((((((((100*y-x) *y-x) *y-x) *y-x) *y-x) *y-x) *y-x) *y-x) *y-x)
>   *y-x) *y-x) *y-x = 0, x = 9.8](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28100%2ay-x%29+%2ay-x%29+%2ay-x%29+%2ay-x%29+%2ay-x%29+%2ay-x%29+%2ay-x%29+%2ay-x%29+%2ay-x%29+%2ay-x%29+%2ay-x%29+%2ay-x%29%29+%3D+0%2C+x+%3D+9.8&dataset=)

I've tried using [capital sigma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) and [capital PI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Capital_Pi_notation) but both of them can't seem to be able to express the above equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your context and needs you can either view it as iteration of a function:
$$ f^{12}(100) \qquad\text{where }f(z)=zy-x $$

or you can apply the distributive law and get
$$ 100y^{12} - xy^{11} - xy^{10} - \cdots - xy^2 - xy - x $$

which after a bit more rearrangement becomes
$$ 100y^{12} - x\frac{y^{12}-1}{y-1} $$

Comment: Do you happen to know how we can type `f12(100) where f(z) = zy - x; x = 9.8` into wolfram alpha to solve for `y`?

Comment: @Pacerier: No. $ $

Comment: @Pacerier use the Nest command. WA accept something like "Solve[ Nest[y*#-9.8 &,100,12] == 0, y]" and give you [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve[Nest[y*%23-9.8+%26%2C100%2C12]%3D%3D0%2Cy])